# Regular expression matching strings with at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 number and 1 special character from a list

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's the regex expression

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\-$*.{}?"!@#%&\/\\,><':;|_~`^\]\[\)\(]).{8,}
```

This currently makes sure that a string contains at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 number and one special character from a list.

What I want is to make sure I don't allow white spaces but I could not find a way to do it.

Comment: Looks like there's an answer to your question here: stackoverflow.com/questions/3466850/… although, it's probably more efficient to construct 4 separate regular expressions and evaluate them against your string...

Comment: Hi Lorincz, the problem in your regex was that you were looking behind for all characters. I narrowed it to all BUT whitespaces, and it works: `/^(?=[^\s]*[a-z])(?=[^\s]*[A-Z])(?=[^\s]*[0-9])(?=[^\s]*[\-$*.{}?"!@#%&\/\\,><':;|_~`^\]\[\)\(]).{8,}/`

Comment: [ANy Characters](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%28%3F%3D.*%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5BA-Z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5B0-9%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5B%5C-%24*.%7B%7D%3F%22!%40%23%25%26%5C%2F%5C%5C%2C%3E%3C'%3A%3B%7C_~%60%5E%5C%5D%5C%5B%5C%29%5C%28%5D%29.%7B8%2C%7D%2F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `.` to `\S`:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\-$*.{}?"!@#%&\/\\,><':;|_~`^\]\[\)\(])\S{8,}$
```

Comment: I don't think this is working, tested out on https://regex101.com and this "Qwerty123 *" resulted in one match(Qwerty123), which is not what I really wanted

Comment: You would have to anchor the end of the string with a `$` then. I've update the answer accordingly.